# Open a link in a child window

Tags: php, html, mysqli

[image]

when either Project or No is clicked, they open in a new window with other details under that clicked row, but i want them to open in a child window instead. is there a way to do it?
this is my code

```
<table id="keywords" class="container">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
          <td><span>Project</span></td>
            <td><span>No</span></td>
          <td><span>Sub ID</span></td>
          <td><span>Name</span></td>
          <td><span>Requested Amount</span></td>
          <td><span>Paid Amount</span></td>
          <td><span>Amount To be Paid</span></td> 
          <td><span>Description</span></td>
          <td><span>State</span></td>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php

/* showing table */

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM memo ORDER BY No DESC, SubID ASC"
                    or die("Failed to query database" .mysqli_error());
                $result = $link->query($sql);    

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    print "<tr>"; 
                    print "<td ><a href=\"Project.php?Project={$row['Project']}\">"  . $row['Project'] . "</a></td>";
                    print "<td ><a href=\"PaymentVoucher.php?No={$row['No']}\">"  . $row['No'] . "</a></td>";
                    print "<td >" . $row['SubID'] . "</td>";
                    print "<td ><a href=\"Name.php?Name={$row['Name']}\">"  . $row['Name'] . "</a></td>";
                    print "<th >" . $row['RequestAmount'] . "</th>";
                    print "<th >" . $row['PaidAmount'] . "</th>";
                    print "<th >" . $row['AmountToPay'] . "</th>";
                    print "<td >" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
                    print "<td >" . $row['State'] . "</td>";
                    print "</tr>"; 

                    }
                    // print "</table>"; 

?> 
</table>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by child-window? An iframe that opens right under your selected row?

Comment: no not an iframe. when you click on one of the Projects, it should open as a pop up window which includes the data of that specific row